# Convert docx or doc to PDF in android using Apache Poi library

Tags: pdf, apache-poi, docx, doc

I am **Converting docx or doc to PDF in android using apache poi library** -

I used this dependency in my gradle file -

**implementation "fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf:1.0.5"**

and this is code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument
import java.io.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        convertPDf.setOnClickListener {
            //1 st
            try {
                    val doc: InputStream = FileInputStream(File("storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/Resume.docx"))
                    val document = XWPFDocument(doc)
                    val options: PdfOptions = PdfOptions.create()
                    val out: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(File("/storage/emulated/0/Movies/file-Sample-ConvertedToPDF.pdf"))
                    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options)
            } catch (ex: FileNotFoundException) {
                Log.i("printer", "exception in converting pdf =>${ex.message}")
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                Log.i("printer", "exception in converting pdf =>${ex.message}")
            }
}
```

but it gives me this error

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 20719
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Color;**

is any other way to resolve this or way to converting doc to pdf in android

Comment: same issue any solution?